# Remove specific word's from url using .htacsess

Tags: category, url-rewrite, frontend, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite and remove some words from the URL using .htaccess.

I have en url like this:

> http://example.com/es/ropita-de-bebe/**chica**/vestidos.html/

and I want to leave it like this:

> http://example.com/es/ropita-de-bebe/vestidos.html/

I'm not very familiar with `.htaccess` rewrites,

Can someone help me.

**UPDATE**
I didn't find the working solution using the .htaccees, in general the answer worked (did change the url's), but as a result, all the pages showed 404.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this (simple, but not very fast method) is to export the table of `core_url_rewrites` and the change in bulk and re-upload the changes.

I hope this answer will set you on the right track :)

Answer (score 1):

**To remove 'chica' from the url**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-chica-(.*).html$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1-$2.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

**To remove 'chica' from the url** http://example.com/es/ropita-de-bebe/chica/vestidos.html

```
RewriteRule ^chica/(.*)\.html$ $1-vestidos.html [L,R=301]
```

**To remove 'chica' from the url** http://example.com/es/ropita-de-bebe/chica/vestidos.html

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/chica/(.*).html$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/$2.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but now in every url I receive the 404, is it normal? I did clean the cache, but didn't reindex yet, because I have a lot of products and reindex will take ages. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Hello, I've reindexed all the website and still getting 404 error on the affected pages, any suggestions? Thank you